ошибка при сборке линукс ядра 2.6.22.18
возникает ошибка при сборке uImage ядра 2.6.22.18 для dlink DGS-1210-10P B1. Собираю на архитектуре feroceon для проца Marvell MV88F6281 и вылетает ошибка, хотя при сборке для MV98D4122 все собирается нормально. В основном все функции из ошибок содержит си файл в linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/plat-feroceon/mv_hal/prestera/mvPrestera.c и linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/plat-feroceon/mv_hal/prestera/mvPrestera.h.
  LD      init/built-in.o
  LD      .tmp_vmlinux1
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mv_init_irq':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./irq.c:137: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mv_map_io':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./sysmap.c:144: undefined reference to `bspReadRegisterInternal'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./sysmap.c:149: undefined reference to `XCAT_INTERNAL_PP_BASE_ADDR_extern'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./sysmap.c:149: undefined reference to `PRESTERA_DEV_ID_REG_OFFSET_extern'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mv_sys_map':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./sysmap.c:83: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvOsIoUncachedAlignedFree':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/linux_oss/mvOs.c:140: undefined reference to `bspCacheDmaFree'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvOsIoUncachedMemalign':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/linux_oss/mvOs.c:115: undefined reference to `bspCacheDmaMalloc'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvEthDefaultsSet':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:556: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:585: undefined reference to `mvPpBitSet'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:586: undefined reference to `mvPpBitSet'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:587: undefined reference to `mvPpWriteReg'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:600: undefined reference to `mvPpBitSet'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:601: undefined reference to `mvPpBitSet'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:602: undefined reference to `mvPpWriteReg'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/eth/gbe/mvEth.c:603: undefined reference to `mvPpWriteReg'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardIsOOBAvalilable':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2850: undefined reference to `standalone_network_mode_RGMII_for_PP'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardChipIsXCat':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2823: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardChipIsXCat2':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2799: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvPpChipIsXCat2Fast':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2665: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvChipFeaturesGet':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2617: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardTclkGet':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:599: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardChipRevGet':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2768: undefined reference to `mvPpGetXcat2ChipRev'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2772: undefined reference to `mvPpGetChipRev'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardSwitchPortsInitFuncGet':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2479: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2481: undefined reference to `mvPpIsChipGE'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2513: undefined reference to `mvPpIsChipFE'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `mvPpEeprom_DB_XCat2A1_48FE_4GP'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `mvPpEeprom_DB_XCat2A1_24GE_4GP'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `simulate_PP_EEPROM_DB_xCat2A0_BGA_24GE_4GP'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `simulate_PP_EEPROM_DB_xCat2A1_QFP_24GE_2SFP'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `simulate_PP_EEPROM_DB_xCat2A0_QFP_24GE_2SFP'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `simulate_PP_EEPROM_4122_24GE_PHY_A0'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:2524: undefined reference to `simulate_PP_EEPROM_2122_24FE'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvBoardMppGet':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/./kw_family/boardEnv/mvBoardEnvLib.c:1153: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/built-in.o: In function `mvSFlashSectorErase':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/arch/arm/mach-feroceon-kw/../plat-feroceon/mv_hal/sflash/mvSFlash.c:739: undefined reference to `mvSwitchReadReg'
drivers/built-in.o: In function `mv_netdev_init':
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/drivers/net/../../arch/arm/plat-feroceon/mv_drivers_lsp/mv_network/mv_ethernet/mv_netdev.c:2510: undefined reference to `mvPpChipIsXCat2'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/drivers/net/../../arch/arm/plat-feroceon/mv_drivers_lsp/mv_network/mv_ethernet/mv_netdev.c:2514: undefined reference to `mvPpFtdllWaXcat2'
/home/DGS-1210-10P/os/linux-2.6.22.18/drivers/net/../../arch/arm/plat-feroceon/mv_drivers_lsp/mv_network/mv_ethernet/mv_netdev.c:2518: undefined reference to `mvPpWriteReg'
make: *** [.tmp_vmlinux1] Error 1
[root@fdc linux-2.6.22.18]#

